# loop through lines in each file in a folder - nested loop

Tags: shell, loops, nested

I don't know why this is not working:

```
for g in *.txt; do for f in $(cat $g); do grep $f annotations.csv; done > ../$f_annot; done
```

I want to loop through each file in a folder, for each file I want to loop through each line and apply the grep command. When I do

```
for f in $(cat file1.txt); do grep $f annotations.csv; done > ../$f_annot
```

It works, it is the nested loop that doesn't output anything, it seems like it is running but it lasts forever and does nothing.

Comment: seems like u get path-file when  cat $g in second step and then grep in the 3rd step .....  for the same scenario have you tried find command with exec/xargs and grep ?   ..... that should work , find was made for these scenarios.

Comment: Also if you want to know your script is actually working ie reading instruction lines and executing them ..... for each line, you could put the set -xv ; command at start of your script.... it starts to print all commands with argument values before executing on the terminal.

Comment: it seems to be doing the job because using set -xv outputs: for f in '$(cat $g)' grep -color=auto comp102671_c2 annotations.csv  -  The problem could be maybe how the output is being saved?

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for how to do that properly. And yes, `$f_annot` is being expanded as the `f_annot` variable so you end up with `> ../` (I'm surprised that didn't explode or error actually). You meant `> ../${f}_annot`.

Comment: really? I use it like $f_annot usually and it works

Comment: I used the while -r read option and it is still not outputting any files: `for g in gene_lists/*.txt; do while read -r f; do grep "$f" annotationsl.csv > ../${f}_annot.txt; done < $g; done`

Comment: and when I use `${f}_annot.txt` the output file it creates is `_annot.txt`

Answer (score 1):

When you hava an empty txt file, `grep $f annotations.csv` will be translated into a grep command reading from stdin.

You might want to use something like

```
for g in *.txt; do
   grep -f $g annotations.csv > ../$g_annot
done
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

```
for file in *list.txt; do 
   while read -r line; do 
      grep "$line" annotations.csv 
   done < "$file" 
   > ${file}_annot.txt 
done
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

I get

> Cannot write to a directory.
>
> ksh: ../: 0403-005 Cannot create the specified file.

But this is because `$f_annot` evaluates to what we expect. It should be better with `${f}_annot`:

```
for g in *.txt; do for f in $(cat $g); do grep $f annotations.csv; done > ../${f}_annot ; done
```

But there is an issue in your script because it erase the result of some loops: `$f` always has the last value of the loop. Maybe this suits your need better:

```
for g in *.txt; do for f in $(cat $g); do grep $f annotations.csv; done ; done
```